# Tipping bucket rain gauge datalogger using Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have rain gauge that has a PCB that counts the number of tips. From that PCB there is a output wire. I want to connect my Pi to that wire and count the number of tips and store the values for every half an hour or so. The whole setup should run on a battery.

I am planning to use `weewx` python library to do counting and storing data. But I want to know which terminal I should be connecting the rain gauge wire.

Comment: too broad for SO; you need to be more specific, and show us what you've tried and failed with so far.

Comment: I have rain gauge that has a pcb that counts the number of tips, from that pcb there is a output wire, I want to connect my pi to that wire and count the number of tips and store the values for every half an hour or so. I am planning to use weewx python library to do counting and storing data. But I want to know which terminal i should be connecting the raingauge wire.

Comment: put that in the QUESTION.

Comment: I edited the question to add the details that you provided. Could you also edit the question to includes answers to the following questions: How many terminals are there? Which terminals have you tried? What happened on those attempts?

Comment: I am able to connect the output wire from raingauge to p1 terminal of raspberry pi. how to see the data/output or even to see the whether pi is able to access the rain gauge pcb.